# Given a directed graph, give an adjacency list representation of the graph that leads BFS to find the following spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory

Given a directed graph:

[image]

give an adjacency list representation of the graph that leads Breadth first search to find the spanning tree in the left below. And give an adjacency list representation that leads to the right tree below.

[image]

---

I don't quite understand this question. Is it as simple as writing up the adjacency list for the graphs in the second picture? I would assume so if it weren't for the fact that I was given the directed graph. What do I use the directed graph for? I was thinking the adjacency list for the left would be

========================

A| B C

B| E D

C| F

D| G

E|

F|

I can't imagine that's right though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the point of the question is to make one adjacency list for the first directed graph (call it A) such that a BFS of that adjacency list produces the first tree (call it B) and another ordering of the adjacency list for A that produces C.

In other words, the question is about how you order the adjacency list of a directed graph such that the resulting tree from a BFS will have a particular order. You could think of it like a map from {'A', 'B', 'C', ... } to {0, 1, 2, ...} such that visiting the graph by BFS produces one particular tree.

Comment: how do you "order" an adjacency list of a directed graph?..

Comment: It's important to realise that vertex labels like 'A', 'B', 'C', ... are just arbitrary labels - the fact that they have a natural order (alphabetic) is not important. What you want is an ordering of these labels such that visiting (by BFS) *in that order* will give you a particular tree.

Comment: can you take a look at my posted answer? I think i understood your tip

Answer (score 1):

I have attempted the answer based on what Gilleain has told me:

ADJ list for left tree:

A| B C

B| D E C

C | F E

D | G E

E | G

F | G E

G |

---

ADJ list for right tree:

A| C B

B| D C E

C | F E

D | G E

E | G

F | G E

G |

When doing BFS on both graphs it gives the corresponding trees.

Comment: Seems about right, although without an implementation of BFS to hand, it's a bit tricky to check on paper! The point here must be that once you've visited a vertex once, you don't re-visit it from another parent, so vertices in the resulting tree end up being in different places (E, and G). Since the ordering in the adj list is different, the visit order is different, so the resulting tree structure is different.